# Dealing with different html tags in the same item field with scrapy

Tags: html, python-2.7, scrapy

If my html contains a table where columns represent fields and rows represent records but some of the cells in the first column are just text and some are links, how can I get these to all go into the correct field?  I could only think how to do it by omitting the first column all together and .

eg:

```
<tbody>
<tr id="ps_134922471">
<td><a href="/114911935">184A Kent St</a></td>
<td class="center">House</td>
<td class="currency price">$600,000</td>
<td>Auction</td>
<td class="center bed">4</td>
<td class="date">19/10/13</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ps_134922515">
<td>5/189 Rockingham Beach Rd</td>
<td class="center">Unit</td>
<td class="currency price">$502,000</td>
<td>Normal Sale</td>
<td class="center bed">3</td>
<td class="date">10/09/13</td>
</tr>
```

etc... etc...

My nasty solution that omits the first column (which happens to be the street address):

```
def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       items = []
       item = SoldItem()
       types = hxs.select('//table[@id="recentSales"]/tbody/tr/td[@class="center"]/text()').extract()
       beds = hxs.select('//table[@id="recentSales"]/tbody/tr/td[@class="center bed"]/text()').extract()
       prices = hxs.select('//table[@id="recentSales"]/tbody/tr/td[@class="currency price"]/text()').extract()
       dates =  hxs.select('//table[@id="recentSales"]/tbody/tr/td[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
       for i in range(len(types)):
           item['type'] = types[i]
           item['bed'] = beds[i]
           item['price'] = prices[i]
           item['saledate'] = dates[i]
           items.append(item)
       return items
       pass
```

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you loop on table rows `tr` elements. `hxs.select()` will return a list of selectors, on which you can continue to use `.select()` with other relative XPath expressions within the context of each row.

To get the text content of the first `td` cell of each row, whether there's a nested link or not, you can use the `.//text()` pattern to extract **all descendant text nodes**, not only direct children (as with `./text()`)

Also, you need to instantiate an `SoldItem()` **for each iteration** of the loop.
Try something like that:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []

    rows = hxs.select('//table[@id="recentSales"]/tbody/tr)
    for row in rows:
        item = SoldItem()
        item['address'] = row.select('td[1]//text()').extract()
        item['saletype'] = row.select('td[4]/text()').extract()
        item['type'] = row.select('td[@class="center"]/text()').extract()
        item['bed'] = row.select('td[@class="center bed"]/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = row.select('td[@class="currency price"]/text()').extract()
        item['saledate'] = row.select('td[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: Thanks paul t.  This makes perfect sense.  Should I be using base spider or crawl spider?  I am getting an error: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 575, in _runCallbacks
     current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)

Comment: Using the crawl spider takes care of the errors but I'm not getting any results.  Is this because I have not specified any rules?

Comment: If you're using `CrawlSpider` you should NOT override `parse`, so you need to rename it, and reference your callback(s) in the `Rules`. If you use `BaseSpider`, `parse` is the default callback, and you need to implement the "next pages" logic (yielding requests to other pages) yourself.

Comment: Oh -- Indenting is the cause of wasted couple of hours !!!   Thanks for your help paul t.